# Fetch() Response.text() is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

First off I am sorry if this question has been asked before, I tried other similar questions and the answers didn't help me.

I am using `fetch()` to grab a UTF-8 encoded file, but my `response.text()` keeps returning `undefined`. I have tested it in Postman and it returns the encoded data no problem.

Sample Code:

```js
async function testCode() {
  const response = await fetch(url1);
  const data = await response.text();
  console.log(response);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

Console.log(data):

```
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "219BA1C8-5BF8-41E3-97C9-BA0A7684D712", "name": "mgaonline.ubx", "offset": 0, "size": 9416, "type": "application/ubx"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "219BA1C8-5BF8-41E3-97C9-BA0A7684D712", "name": "mgaonline.ubx", "offset": 0, "size": 9416, "type": "application/ubx"}}, "bodyUsed": true, "headers": {"map": {"cache-control": "private", "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=mgaonline.ubx", "content-length": "9416", "content-type": "application/ubx", "date": "Tue, 30 Jun 2020 14:17:13 GMT", "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0", "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319", "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "https://online-live1.services.u-blox.com/GetOnlineData.ashx?token=Janf2Rk0CkKHlMi2hWUOjg;gnss=gps,glo,gal,qzss;datatype=eph,alm,aux;"}
```

And when I try to access that `[Object]` it just comes out as `undefined`
But in Postman it returns the proper 8bit binary data encoded in utf-8.

Comment: Have a look here https://javascript.info/fetch

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi it's not json, it's their own ubx type but I will try with that

Comment: Can you show the "console.log(data)"? Silly question but are you sure it's a GET request you need ?

Comment: @Arcord will post in the question as an edit as it's much too long as a comment

Comment: Sure :-) And when you try a ".blob()" or a ".arrayBuffer()" do you get something do you get something ? If yes I guess it's related to the content of the accept header you get in the response... Since the browser don't know it (don't think it's a standard one) maybe he refused to deliver you the thing as a text ?

Comment: @Arcord well arrayBuffer is not implemented in react-native but when I try .blob() I get the same data but with `[Object]` as `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have learned that React-Native doesn't support encoded binary data for whatever reason by default and had to use `rn-fetch-blob` which worked immediately as it should. That was a waste of 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting content type in headers, ,might work

`fetch(url1, { Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8} );`

Comment: The content-type listed in the returned header is "application/ubx" so I tried headers of:
const myHeaders = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/ubx",
  Accept: "application/ubx",
  charset: "utf-8"
});

Comment: A "content-type" header does not really make sense in a GET request (so without a body) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type ... Do you mean "Accept" header ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  const utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
  const response = await fetch(fileURL);
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  let { value: chunk, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
  chunk = chunk ? utf8Decoder.decode(chunk) : '' ;
```

from [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I can't because the data itself is not JSON parsable:
```SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"```

Comment: I've edited my answer can you try that please and `console.log(chunk)`

Comment: I have tried that but get this error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.body.getReader')`
There seems to be no attribute `body` on `response`